# How to explain this map syntax?

Tags: go

I am going through the following Go Lang Map data structure. I am little confused with the syntax -

```
//this is fine
countryCapitalMap = make(map[string]string)
/* insert key-value pairs in the map*/
countryCapitalMap["France"] = "Paris"
capital, ok := countryCapitalMap["United States"]

/* print map using keys*/
for country := range countryCapitalMap {
    fmt.Println("Capital of", country, "is", countryCapitalMap[country])
}
```

Is it that the countryCapitalMap["United States"] returns two return values from the following line

```
capital, ok := countryCapitalMap["United States"]
```

Or countryCapitalMap[country] returns single value from the following line

```
fmt.Println("Capital of", country, "is", countryCapitalMap[country])
```

How could I decipher this syntax? Is it based on *where and which statement* the expression is used with?

Comment: It's called the "comma ok" idiom. It is supported by a couple expressions in Go, like map indexing, type assertions and channel receives. These expressions return either a single value or two values where the second is the ok flag indicating success or failure. For these expressions to return the two values they need to be on the right hand side of an assignment expression (`=`/`:=`) and on the left hand side of that expression two variables must be specified.

Comment: [Go here](https://golang.org/ref/spec) and CTRL/CMD+F for the string `, ok`. The name "comma ok" can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) (again use CTRL/CMD+F).

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva. How the expression knows that it has to return a single value or multiple values ? Is it inferred on the variables mentioned on the left hand side ? - (kind of method overloading )

Comment: Yes it is inferred by the compiler from the number of variables on the left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I decipher this syntax?

Read the definition of the syntax.

A primary expression of the form

```
a[x]
```

denotes the element of the map a indexed by x. The value x is called the index or map key.

There is a special form of an index expression on a map.

```
v, ok = a[x]
v, ok := a[x]
var v, ok = a[x]
```

yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
>
> A primary expression of the form
>
> ```
> a[x]
> ```
>
> denotes the element of the array, pointer to array, slice, string or
>   map a indexed by x. The value x is called the index or map key,
>   respectively.
>
> For a of map type M:
>
> - x's type must be assignable to the key type of M
> - if the map contains an entry with key x, a[x] is the map element with key x and the type of a[x] is the element type of M
> - if the map is nil or does not contain such an entry, a[x] is the zero value for the element type of M
>
> Otherwise a[x] is illegal.
>
> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment
>   or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x]
> v, ok := a[x]
> var v, ok = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
>   the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.

---